# How can input:focus stay on focused even if redirected to another html file?

Tags: css

How can input:focus retain the focus even if it is redirected to another HMTL file?

I also tried input:active and input:target.

CSS

```
.titleBar input:focus{
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #3c3c5d;

}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="titleBar">
            <input type="button" value="Dashboard" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">
           <input type="button" value="Employee Information" onclick="window.location.href='employees.html'">
           <input type="button" value="Customer Information">
           <input type="button" value="Financial Information">
           <input type="button" value="Presentation Materials">
           <input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="window.location.href='login.html'">
        </div>
```

It should remain focused when it is redirected to another html file when the input is clicked. It will remain focused until another input is clicked

Answer (score 0):

This is not achievable only with CSS. You need to write some JS code too.

```
const makeActive = () => {
    document.getElementById('thatInput').focus();
}
```

And you can call this function whenever you are redirecting to another html. 
Note: I trid `autofocus`, it didn't work.